# Iterate Table and Replace Cell Text Under Certain Conditions

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have a table like this in my markup:

```
<table class="wowClassTable">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Race</td>
    <td>Faction</td>
    <td>Link</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Human</td>
    <td>Alliance</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.wowwiki.com/Human_(playable)">View</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dwarf</td>
    <td>Alliance</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.wowwiki.com/Dwarf_(playable)">View</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Night Elf</td>
    <td>Alliance</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.wowwiki.com/Night_elf_(playable)">View</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is iterate over the table have the following array returned:

```
[["Race", "Faction", "Link"], ["Human", "Alliance", "View"], ["Dwarf", "Alliance", "View"], ["Night Elf", "Alliance", "View"]]
```

However I want the third element of the array to have the "View" text replaced with the actual link. So to first iterate over the table and get the array I did this:

```
race_table_array = Array.new

rows.each do |row|
  race_array = Array.new
  row.cells.each do |cell|
    race_array << cell.text
  end
  race_table_array << race_array
end

puts race_table_array.inspect
```

That got me the array. So then I tried replacing the text and here I'm at a loss. I know I need to reference the link element in the cell. So I changed my row.cells iterator above to this:

```
row.cells.each do |cell|
  if cell.a(text: 'View').exists?
    race_array << cell.a(:href)
  else
    race_array << cell.text
  end
end
```

My thinking there was I'll reference the nested 'a' (link) element inside the cell (which is a TableCell object). I'll find the element by the text 'View'. Once I have that, I'll use the href. This gives an inkling of working but is replacing my entire array so I end up with this:

```
[["Race", "Faction", "Link"], "http://www.wowwiki.com/Human_(playable)", "http://www.wowwiki.com/Dwarf_(playable)", "http://www.wowwiki.com/Night_elf_(playable)"]]
```

If guessing this has to do with how I'm checking if the cell has a link called 'View' but I'm not sure how to correct the problem at this point.

Comment: Should `Race, Faction & Link` actually be `<th>` and not `<td>` ?  You can then do a quick check to make sure you're dealing with `<td>` and then just push each element individually into your array.

Comment: From good web design perspective, the initial row should be `th` elements, no doubt. While my example contents are fake, the table is based on how most tables in my company are constructed. Currently, however, I can grab all the `td` elements without problem. (My first iterator populated the array exactly as I want it.) It's just that when I'm on the third `td` element of a given row, I need to grab the link's `href` text and then return _that_ as if it was the cell text rather than the literal 'View' text that's actually in the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally i will go with more functional aproach and clean the code a little bit.

```
rows.map do |row|
  row.cells.map do |cell|
    cell.a(text: 'View').exists? ?  cell.a(text: 'View').href : cell.text
  end
end
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: You've absolutely helped! That is a very elegant bit of code there. I appreciate you adding that here. I certainly plan on using your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have an answer and it seems to be a non too terribly inelegant one.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
rows.each do |row|
  race_array = Array.new
  row.cells.each do |cell|
    if cell.a(text: 'View').exists?
      race_array << cell.a(text: 'View').href
    else
      race_array << cell.text
    end
  end
  race_table_array << race_array
end
```

The difference there is that instead of doing this (as I originally was):

```
race_array << cell.a(:href)
```

I'm doing this:

```
race_array << cell.a(text: 'View').href
```

What that does is get me the following:

```
[["Race", "Faction", "Link"], ["Human", "Alliance", "http://www.wowwiki.com/Human_(playable)"], ["Dwarf", "Alliance", "http://www.wowwiki.com/Dwarf_(playable)"], ["Night Elf", "Alliance", "http://www.wowwiki.com/Night_elf_(playable)"]]
```

Looks pretty good to me! I don't know if this is the best way to do it necessarily, but it certainly seems to work.